# Разграничение доступа. Управление доступом к файлам и папкам

Tags: c++, qt, access-control

Здравствуйте прошу совета, задание для курсовой реализовать модель разграничения доступа Take-grant, пишу графику на QT, на данный момент реализовал авторизацию с сохранением данных в SQL. Нужна подсказка для реализации разграничения доступа. Совсем не могу представить как реализовать задачу. Буду благодарен за любую подсказку и наводку. Есть такой критерий к заданию, что доступ к файлам должен ограничиваться только когда работает приложение.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос описан не вполне ясно. Вы хотите чтобы ваша запущенная программа позволяла или запрещала доступ к файлам в том числе из других программ?
В своё время я это делал с использованием SetWindowsHookEx, отслеживанием LoadLibraryA/LoadLibraryW и подменой файловых API на свои. К сожалению это было очень давно и исходников не сохранилось.

Сейчас подходы несколько изменились и хуки на api ставят более элегантно. Почитайте к примеру эту статью https://habr.com/ru/company/icl_services/blog/324718/

Comment: Мне хотя бы запретить доступ пользователя к файлам и папкам. У меня вроде идея написать функцию которая запомнит атрибуты доступа файлов, потом функцию которая изменит атрибуты, и последнюю которая вернет все в исходное состоянии перед закрытием